# Buck converter AP65111A gives no power when bootstrap capacitor is connected

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I'm using AP65111A buck converter and it works *fine*. It has typical beginner-level ripples, somehow manages to keep the voltage under moderate load and so on.

However, following the schematic 1:1 for 3.3V output yielded literally no power output under load.
Output capacitor is 22uF MLCC cap and input voltage is 6.5V (kind of non-negotiable factor in my use).

After I removed the capacitor C5, the converter started outputting power normally, but it gets massive voltage drop when 0.4A load is applied. It drops about 1.2-1.5V and doesn't recover even though feedback voltage is too low.

[image: AP65111A typical application]

My problems being:

1. Why adding bootstrap capacitor causes converter to not output any power?
2. The IC is rated for 1.5A continuous current but gets hot and cuts off at ~1.4W (0.4A@3.3V). Could it be fault of improper value of inductor or output capacitor?
3. Could input voltage be a deciding factor here?

Cheers

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the specs for capacitors and inductors and also the PCB layout. It should work worse when the capacitor is removed.

Comment: Could be a layout issue.  Which inductor are you using?  A link to the inductor datasheet would be helpful.

Comment: Add a link to the data sheet.

Comment: Inductor: https://www.tme.eu/Document/a7bba15336bc08baa49ff14d85d5dea0/WALSIN_WLPN242410%20Series.pdf
IC: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP65111A.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding an external bootstrap diode from V_in (anode) to BST (cathode)? Could be schottky. That should get you up and running I would think.